# How to connect 2 devices using react-native-webrtc

Tags: react-native, webrtc

I am trying to connect 2 devices (android) using the react-native-webrtc library.

I understood the idea: create a peer connection, then create an offer (that return an SDP). My problem is : I don't know how to send this offer to peer, and how I can create an answer from it.

I tried to pass the SDP by copy/pass between the devices, but I got few error like "can't use createAnswer() from this state", or simply nothing happened. In my code exemple, I have 2 buttons that calls the 2 functions, and an InputText to copy the offer.

I'm not sure if I have to use an ICE server, or use something else like socket...

```js
configuration = {
    iceServers: [{ url: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" }]
  };

  // LocalConnection
  pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
  pc.createOffer().then(desc => {
    pc.setLocalDescription(desc);
    console.log("Offer", JSON.stringify(desc));
  });
}

function createAnswer(sdp) {
  pc.createAnswer(sdp).then(desc => {
    pc.setRemoteDescription(desc);
    console.log("Pc remote answer", desc);
  });
}
```

Expected: device 2 creates an answer from device 1 offer
Actual : don't have any connection

Comment: Same problem here? Any solutions?